# Possible bug in webkit browsers for "text-align: start" style table headers

Tags: html, css

If I use *text-align:start;* on a **TH** element in a HTML **TABLE**, I expect the content to align on the left (in an LTR language context). Instead it remains in the center:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>Default TD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:start;">Start TD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:end;">End TD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Default TH</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="text-align:start;">Start TH</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="text-align:end;">End TH</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/w5JNZ/1/)

It should look like this...

[image: Desired output]

...but instead looks like this...

[image: Actual output]

Note that the **TD** element behaves as expected.

I get this behaviour in Chrome 32.0.1700.107 and Safari 7.0.1 so I'm assuming it's a webkit bug, but I wanted to check my assumptions.

Comment: `text-align:start` is an experimental feature and should not be used for production code. Perhaps it's not enabled in your version of Chrome.: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

Comment: According to the compatibility table on that page, it should be supported in Chrome and Safari since versions 1.0 and 3.1 respectively (i.e. the beginning of time). You are right that it is clearly labeled as experimental though.

Comment: Supported but might need a switch turning on in Chrome settings.

Comment: Works fine here. Chrome Version 33.0.1750.117 m

Comment: @SonuJoshi does the "m" suffix imply the Mac OSX version? I upgraded to that version of Chrome and I see the same problem. I should probably have said I'm running on OS X 10.9.1

Comment: @RupertRawnsley No. I checked it on windows.

Comment: I have the same issue in Chromium 31 under Linux, so it's not just a Mac issue.

Comment: A workaround would be to use Javascript to find out if the direction is LTR or RTL and apply `left` or `right` respectively. But I assume you knew that already.

Comment: @MrLister thanks for the confirmation. Feel free to suggest the workaround as an answer and I will raise a bug report.

Comment: Hm, unfortunately I just found I don't know a sure-fire way to determine with Javascript if the `text-align` is `start` or not. I created [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5JNZ/5/), and it works, but only if the style is inline. If it isn't, you'd have to use the `getComputedStyle` function, and that one doesn't show the difference between `start` and `center`. Sorry.

Comment: @MrLister Ah, I think we can do something similar in CSS. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a bug and I've submitted it to the Chrome team, so I'll answer with a workaround (based on a suggestion by @MrLister).

We can use the CSS dir selector like this:

```
th.startFix {
    text-align:start;
}
/* Not needed once text-align: start is fully supported for TH elements */
[dir="ltr"] th.startFix { text-align: left; } 
[dir="rtl"] th.startFix { text-align: right; }
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/w5JNZ/6/)

Answer (score 0):

`text-align:start` and `text-align:left` will do the same.

Actually, `<td style="text-align:start;">Start TD</td>` also doesn't work.

If you dont want to use 'left' property then try this

`<th style="direction: rtl;text-align:end;">Start TH</th>`.

It shows that the default start for the `<th>` is at the center of the row. You can check it by try the alternates.

http://jsfiddle.net/bf6ZU/

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Well, 1) the official definition says `start` should do the same as `left` (in an LTR environment). 2) in most other browsers, it does! 3) In addition, if you do `<center style="text-align:start">...</center>` it also aligns the contents to the left. So there's no indication whatsoever that `text-align:start` is supposed to be the same as `text-align:initial`.

Comment: @MrLister: yes, i shouldnt have said tat they both do same. Me too looked into the official def. I was just tried to solve the issue. Thanks for correcting me.